# Can I make text inside a div not visible but still have it use space?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="button" id="test1">Login</div>
```

Is there a way using jQuery that I can make the text invisible but 
still have it occupy the same amount of space? Please note I still need the button and its colored background visible. Just want to hide the text. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

this will do it

```
$('#test1').css('opacity','0');
```

**Update**

```
<div class="button" id="test1"><span>Login</span></div>

$('#test1').children().css('visibility','hidden');
```

Comment: How can I do this for the text inside of the #test1 div and not the div itself ?

Comment: check the update, you can wrap the text with a span and hide the span

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.button').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

`visibility:hidden` keeps the space as it is.

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there a way to show it again if I need to ?

Comment: this could also be done in pure css. (I know the OP asked about jquery)

Comment: I just noticed. This will hide the button. But what I need to do is to just hide the text. I want to keep the button and its background.

Comment: use the same color for text and background

Comment: @dr - The problem is the background is a gradient.

Comment: then wrap the text into another element and hide this wrapper instead of the div

Answer (score 1):

`transparent` is a  valid color, you may apply it to the text:

```
$('#test1').css('color','transparent');
```

---

Related to the comment:

**Setting the color to transparent and storing the original color:**

```
$('#test1')
      .each(function(){var o=$(this);
                       if(!o.data('color')){o.data('color',o.css('color'))}})
        .css('color','transparent');
```

Restore the original color:

```
$('#test1').css( 'color', function(){return $(this).data('color');} )
```

Comment: But if I do this then how can I restore the original color?

Comment: call css() again with the desired color. If you don't want to hardcode the original color, you may store the original color inside the element's data before you set the transparent color and retrieve it later to show the text again.